# What backward-compatible XSD changes can be made?

Tags: java, xml, rest, xsd

How can I make changes to an XML Schema for a REST interface without impacting consuming applications (if they do not upgrade)?

Comment: Do these existing consumers validate the XML data against the (old) schema? If they do, you don't have a lot of options. You can't add new elements and attributes, even optional ones, because they don't exist in the older version of the schema and hence don't validate.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples of ***request*** XSD changes that you can and cannot do to maintain backward compatibility with the previous interface version.

### Can do

1. Add optional elements or attributes.
2. Change requiredness from required to optional.
3. Add values to enumerations.

### Cannot do

1. Add or delete required elements or attributes.
2. Change element or attribute names.
3. Change requiredness from optional to required.
4. Remove values from enumerations.

Comment: You need to rephrase your answer to consider the direction of the message; as it stands, your answer it is partially wrong. For example, adding a required element in the response may not break an older client. One may remove an enumerated value from a response (where there is more than one), without an adverse impact.

Comment: @PetruGardea An extra required element in the response would still pose a problem if the existing consumer validated the response against the (old) schema.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt - if the consumer validates the response against the old schema, then there are two options here (to keep the question relevant): a) if the field is optional or not, the server must "shave" the new fields to match the client's version, or b) the client schemas are forward compatible, so the server doesn't need to do anything. In both cases, your point becomes irrelevant. Your comment is also giving out incorrect information, as it ignores the fact that the schema may have been set forward compatible,i.e. using some sort of xsd:any/anyAttribute that may validate additional content

Comment: @PetruGardea I don't see any mention in the OP's question of having done anything special to making the schema "forward compatible". If the OP had such foresight, I'm sure he or she would have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: @PetruGardea: I've updated my answer to clarify that it pertains to ***request*** message changes.   I invite you to write a corresponding answer for ***responses*** as I respect your expertise in the area.   I am sure you'll take care not to assume anything about a caller's implementation other than the constraints explicit in interface definition.  Thank you.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, :) ... you keep speculating: "I'm sure he or she would have mentioned that in the question"...  Rhetoric question of course, what makes you think that? I am rather of opinion that the person asking doesn't know much about XSD anyway, if only because s/he thinks REST is relevant here... Which is why I think that any comment/answer that is not sufficiently qualified to be true regardless of the context, is misleading, at least; e.g. you ignored wildcards when you said "You can't add new elements and attributes, even optional ones, because they don't exist in the older version".

Answer (score 0):

1. Just don't alter the existing schema and structures to ensure backward compatibility.
2. Only add optional elements and attributes as required to extend the functionality.
3. Always version your services - either URL way or Content-Type way! This is to ensure maintainability.