# How to add fields to XML document without making the recipient change his/her schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an application which sends same XML document to many systems. Now one of the systems wants to get one field extra.
The question is how can I add the field to the document and send it to all system without breaking their process. in a different wor, how can I make other systems to ignore the added field?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this without breaking existing recipients unless the recipients have been designed with this kind of change in mind.

It's very common for XML systems to specify a policy of "if you don't understand an element, then ignore it", and if you have such a policy, and people follow it, then adding new optional fields becomes easy. But if no such policy is in place, or if it hasn't been tested in anger, then adding fields risks breakage.

At the level of the schema, new fields can be added as optional elements or attributes. If the extensions are customisations for a particular client or group of clients, then you might want to consider putting the extra elements or attributes into a different namespace so they don't clash with extensions invented by someone else. This also allows you to exploit XSD schema wildcards which make any content valid provided it is in a different namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can Keep newly added  field as optional.
 look at this discussion [What backward-compatible XSD changes can be made?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198785/what-backward-compatible-xsd-changes-can-be-made)  for detail

Answer (score 0):

> The question is how can I add the field to the document and send it to
>   all system without breaking their process?

That depends.

- If you can recompile all the other systems, and those systems have got auto-code generation to consume the XSD (e.g. they use something like `xsd.exe` for .NET/C#, or similar for other languages), then you can simply modify the schema.

  - As auto-code-generation is being used, the remaining code changes to be done by an actual developer are comparatively small. As the risk / time involved in making schema changes is largely dealt with by the auto-code-generation, the impact on the project is low.
  - Personally speaking I favour this route for large projects because it allows changes late on in a project for very little risk.
- If you can recompile all the other systems, but they've got "hand-crafted" code to interpret and validate the XML, then there's a lot more work to be done. This may deter you from making the changes everywhere, but:

  - Not making the changes universally throughout the systems starts building up engineering debt. If only some systems that handle the changed message are updated, then this is a recipe for future difficulties.
  - Whether or not you can "get away with it" in the short term depends on the policies discussed by Michael Kay in his excellent post.
- If you cannot recompile or modify the other systems, then you are at risk of hitting severe problems. The whole point of the XSD schema is that it is an agreed standard to which every system has committed to follow. You're wanting to break that contract, so it will be entirely unsurprising if things break because of it.

> In a different wor, how can I make other systems to ignore the added
>   field?

Michael Kay and Norman Khan have explained / pointed to excellent advice on this particular aspect of your problem.

**General Point**

Auto code generation of POCO, POJO source code is, if available, an excellent way to help a project. The difficulty is that the tools available to do this vary in quality and completeness.

`xsd.exe` is pretty good I think. I have used it, had good results.

I have tried C# code generators for JSON schemas. JSON schemas themselves are fine - you can express types, structure and size/value constraints (just like XSD and ASN.1). The C# code generators I tried were disappointing in not covering the full JSON schema standard.

My own experience is predominantly with two of the commercial ASN.1 tools. These do for ASN.1 what `xsd.exe` does for XSD/XML. However they are more useful than xsd.exe because they cover:

- C, C++, C# and Java
- all major OSes on all major CPUs, and embedded systems,

ASN.1 is itself useful

- binary (PER, BER, etc) wireformats
- text (XML, JSON, etc) wireformats.

  - this allows interaction with non-ASN.1 aware systems / languages, e.g. javascript, lots of web stuff, etc.
- ASN.1 schema and XSD schema are interchangeable. There is an official standard for translating between the two, and ASN.1 tools often have a conversion utility

  - Thus one system built using ASN.1 tools / schema / libraries can interoperate with another built with the XSD schema using whatever XSD tools and libraries are available, with XML being the wireformat used in between.
  - The ASN.1 and XSD schema are effectively a "single point of truth", with the translation between the two being automatic and part of the build process.

If one has access to these tools one can then have an extremely heterogenous system involving all sorts of different languages, platforms, and technologies, with the interfacing between them all being, effectively, machine generated.

These commercial tools for ASN.1 cost money (like, quite a lot), but for a large project with a lot of complex messaging interactions across a lot of different languages and platforms, it is worth it for the manpower savings and risk reduction.

When faced with a problem similar to yours, I have been able to make schema changes at almost any point in a project requiring very little manpower (often as low as minutes) to deal with the consequences throughout the entire system.