# scala nested XML parsing with CDATA

Tags: xml, scala, xml-parsing, cdata

I have an xml structure to be parsed as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<System>
  <header>
    <identification serialNumber="100"/>
  </header>
  <actionPointList>
    <actionPoint>
        <property><![CDATA[<Event type="Event1" name="EventName1" time="2018-03-27 04:31:02Z">
                <UseCase>Receive</UseCase>
                <LocalIP>103.8.0.31</LocalIP>
                <LocalHost>103.8.0.31</LocalHost>
                </Event>]]>
        </property>
        <property><![CDATA[<Event type="Event2" name="EventName2" time="2018-03-27 05:31:02Z">
                <UseCase>Send</UseCase>             
                <RemoteIP>10.22.0.54</RemoteIP>
                <RemoteHost>10.22.0.54</RemoteHost>
                <StartDateTime>2018-03-27 06:31:01.21</StartDateTime>
                <StopDateTime>2018-03-27 06:31:02.14</StopDateTime>
                <TransferredObjects>1</TransferredObjects>
                <TransferredBytes>354200</TransferredBytes>
                <EncryptionUsed>false</EncryptionUsed>
                </Event>]]>
        </property>
    </actionPoint>
  </actionPointList>
</System>
```

I want to get an array of Events which are in the CDATA.
Is there a simple way to get a list without getting text of each node and then accumulating?
The below code works, but is a bit long:

```
val propertyNodes = myXml \\ "actionPoint" \ "property"
for (propertyNode <- propertyNodes) {
val eventText= propertyNode.text
//Extract from eventText
}
```

Is there a simpler way compared to this?

Comment: Why do you have CDATA sections containing XML code instead of proper XML elements? Does the content model for the `property` element prohibit `Event` elements?

Comment: Well, we can not change the model, this has been designed by someone else long ago. We need to parse logs containing such events :-)

Comment: Surely, models can be updated in non-breaking ways? Unless `property` is required to be an **ëmpty** element.... If you don't update the model, you lose part of the advantages of using XML (both validation and parsing generally).

Comment: See also [What backward-compatible XSD changes can be made?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30198785/6002174)